# Linux Mint 18 suspend issue

Tags: linux-mint, suspend

After fresh installation of Linux Mint 18 64-bit, when I try to suspend screen goes black and system does not suspend (and power led stays on).

Preinstalled kernel with Linux Mint 18 is 4.4.0-21

I am using laptop TOSHIBA-SATELLITE-L50-B, with graphics Intel+AMD:

```
$ inxi -Fxz

Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Jet PRO [Radeon R5 M230] bus-ID: 09:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.3 drivers: ati,radeon,intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.01hz
```

I've found solution and wanted to share in case someone else bumps into this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've solved this issue by installing new linux kernel "4.5.2-040502-generic" following this guidelines:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/761758/ubuntu-16-04-lts-cannot-suspend-fails-on-suspending

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1574125/comments/26

Install new kernel (4.5.2):

```
cd /tmp

wget \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.2-wily/linux-headers-4.5.2-040502_4.5.2-040502.201604200335_all.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.2-wily/linux-headers-4.5.2-040502-generic_4.5.2-040502.201604200335_amd64.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.2-wily/linux-image-4.5.2-040502-generic_4.5.2-040502.201604200335_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.5*.deb linux-image-4.5*.deb
```

Reboot your system and try if suspend works.

In case something goes wrong with new kernel (4.5.2) reboot your computer and select `Advanced options for Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit` in boot menu, then select your old kernel (4.4.0-21).

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly! I followed the steps above and suspend seems to be working great

Comment: Thank you so mutch. This is freaky thing. I lost a couple days to find this TRUE answer.

Comment: Glad to see that this helped you

Comment: 4.5.3 on Linux mint cinnamon worked well and solved suspend problem :)

Comment: Just wanted to mention that 4.5.2 had issues on my machine (Lenovo T440p) but 4.7.5 is working great and fixed the suspend/resume issue.

Comment: Your answer made clear (unlike other online sources) that you need to download the headers_all package, and not just the headers_generic and image_generic. I am testing 4.10.17 (latest 4.10 build) because of it. Thank you for that.

Comment: Unfortunate, I am on kernel 5.15 and am having this same issue.