# Suspend in Linux Mint 18 doesn't work

Tags: suspend

I installed mint on my laptop. All works fine, except suspend (sleep in windows). When I push that button on my laptop, the display is powered of and that's all. The laptop is still working. My model is Extensa-2511. I searched for information via Google but nothing helped me.

My system is:

```
display
         описание: VGA compatible controller
         продукт: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
         производитель: Intel Corporation
         физический ID: 2
         сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:02.0
         версия: 09
         разрядность: 64 bits
         частота: 33MHz
         возможности: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         конфигурация: driver=i915 latency=0
         ресурсы: IRQ:48 память:c0000000-c0ffffff память:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:4000(размер=64)

$ lspci -k | grep VGA -A2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U   Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
Kernel driver in use: i915


$ dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core
ii  xserver-xorg-core   2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2   amd64  Xorg X server - core server
```

ps. swap file exists.

Comment: Please run whatever command gave that output (looks like `lshw`) with `LC_ALL=C`. For example `LC_ALL=C sudo lshw -C display`. That way, the output will be in English.

Comment: *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:c0000000-c0ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra information. It is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Also, comments can be deleted with no warning.

Comment: what i need edit. i need work sleep mode thats all. i guess i need install intel proprietary driver

Comment: Can you execute below command and check `cat mem > /sys/power/state` ?

Comment: sure power # 
cat state 
freeze mem disk

Comment: Duplicate from [Linux Mint 18 suspend issue](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296424)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue by installing new linux kernel "4.5.2-040502-generic" following this guidelines:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/761758/ubuntu-16-04-lts-cannot-suspend-fails-on-suspending

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1574125/comments/26

Install new kernel (4.5.2):

```
cd /tmp

wget \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.2-wily/linux-headers-4.5.2-040502_4.5.2-040502.201604200335_all.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.2-wily/linux-headers-4.5.2-040502-generic_4.5.2-040502.201604200335_amd64.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.2-wily/linux-image-4.5.2-040502-generic_4.5.2-040502.201604200335_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.5*.deb linux-image-4.5*.deb
```

Reboot your system and try if suspend works.

In case something goes wrong with new kernel (4.5.2) reboot your computer and select Advanced options for Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit in boot menu, then select your old kernel (4.4.0-21).

Answer (score 0):

Go to **update manager** and click on **view** and install the latest version of kernel in my case that is **4.4.0-57**