# How to determine which kernel version to install?

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, linux-kernel, suspend

I've recently installed a fresh copy of Linux Mint 18 on my Lenovo T440p and everything is working great except for one thing: I have trouble when resuming from a "Suspend"- I get no GUI, both of my monitors say 'No Input'. Using `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace` to restart the X server seems to fix the problem but of course it kills any running apps I had, which defeats the purpose of me using Suspend in the first place. The default kernel version is 4.4.0-21-generic.

I found [this question/answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296423/linux-mint-18-suspend-issue), but unfortunately Kernel `4.5.2-040502-generic` causes worse problems for me- my desktop doesn't work right, things are running more slowly, and `dmesg` seems to indicate problems (something about a Kernel null dereference- I'm not running the 4.5.2 kernel at the moment so I'm not 100% sure).

So it seems I need a newer version of the Kernel to fix my suspend issue, but I'm not sure how to determine *which* version I should install. Is this generally a trial by error, or is there someplace that keeps track of the stability of kernel releases?

Answer (score 1):

"Something about a Kernel null dereference" sounds like a bug and should be reported as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint), but with more details and the complete error message.

If a **newer** kernel is supposed to fix that (and/or Linux Mint doesn't ship a newer version), you can try a [vanilla kernel](https://www.kernel.org/) instead and report back to [linux-kernel](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-kernel) if it's still not fixed in a current version.

> Is this generally a trial by error, or is there someplace that keeps
>   track of the stability of kernel releases?

Yes. With so many different configurations out there, there's no guarantee that one (kernel) version works for all setups. Fortunately your T440p is a pretty common machine and widely used, so I'd expect that a fix could be already available - if it's really a software issue at all.

Comment: Thanks- while waiting for an answer I just went with "trail by error" and landed on 4.7.5 which seems to be running smoothly and fixed my suspend/resume issue.